# Format an image on a website to display as a title

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

This is the website I'm working with:

http://btwnthelin.es/

I want to render the following image:

[image]

So it will display across the top of the landing page, however what I have now is putting it in the middle of the page, and the sizing is terribly wrong.

Maybe I should use CSS?

How can I fix this issue?

I'm using the template 'fullpage.js'

This is what my index.html page looks like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['#f2f2f2', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke'],
    css3: true
  });
});
```

```css
.section {
  font-size: 6em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
      <img alt="My Image" src='bwn_the_lines.png' style="width:900px;height:300px" />
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="slide">Wusch</div>
      <div class="slide">up</div>
      <div class="slide">dude?</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">:D</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You want image on top of the page?

Comment: yeah, it's supposed to be a title, it's the name of the site you know, so i'd like it to read across the top

Comment: That `jquery.fullpage` which you're using, is adding `vertical-align: middle;` to image's container. You want to start by removing that if you want it on top. And change `img`'s width and height if it's too big.

Comment: what file is that in? how did you know that?

Comment: This one: http://btwnthelin.es/jquery.fullPage.css line#55, I just inspected the element.

Comment: do you know how I might increase the size of that image proportional to the device/browser someone is using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove `vertical-align: middle;` from  `.fp-tableCell` will put your image on top of the page.

And Second issue *"sizing is terribly wrong"*. It is because Your image has given  `height: 300px; width: 900px;`. Just remove it and put with same height and width as it is.

Hope it helps.

Comment: where is `.fp-tableCell`

Comment: `.fp-tableCell` is a class which has css in your `jquery.fullPage.css` file

Comment: I removed that 'align middle` component, and I removed the size specification in the `img` tag, but now it's so small, is there a way to *vector*ishly make it larger?

Comment: Yes you can give size like: `img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 600px;
}` in css file Or you can give class to img tag and give css to that class in you css file.

Comment: but I'd like to to be proportional

Comment: *proportional * means?

Comment: try this: .fp-tableCell{
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -50px;
        margin-left: -450px;
    }

Comment: by proportional I mean, I'd like to dimensions to fit reasonably the situation, i.e. the device or browser being employed, so it will always take up an aestheitically pleasing proportion of the top of the window, you know what I mean?

Comment: @kurenaiKunai where should I put that? please forgive me I'm quite new to web developemnt

Comment: @S.Matthew_English Ok so you should give image size in percentage or you should use JQuery.

Comment: @ketan I guess the percentage thing is like what *kurenaiKunai* has just put, isn't it? What do you mean by use JQuery?

Comment: you can put that in your css file. "fp-tableCell" is the class you are using for the div in your website. Or in the div you can directly put : <div class="fp-tableCell" style="height: 351px; left: 50%; position: absolute; margin-top: -30px; margin-left: -450px;">

Comment: @S.Matthew_English no you do not have to give `position:absolue` you just need to give height in like 10% and width is like: 30% to else.

Comment: @S.Matthew_English LIKE Give `img {
    height: auto;
    width: 50%;
}` will solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Changes made : I added class to your div in this snippet as it is in your website. Secondly i added css property to the div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['#f2f2f2', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke'],
    css3: true
  });
});
```

```css
.section {
  font-size: 6em;
  text-align: center;
}
.fp-tableCell {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="fullpage">
    <div class="fp-tableCell">
      <img alt="My Image" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ubFp.png' style="width:900px;height:300px" />
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="slide">Wusch</div>
      <div class="slide">up</div>
      <div class="slide">dude?</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">:D</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: so the last file is `index.html` and the middle file is `.fullPage.css`, is that right? what is the top file? I see you didn;t get rid of that `style` thing from the tag, does your CSS just override that?

Comment: That top part is your js code, I did'nt make any change to your js file (fullpage.js) that you had in your question, I left it in its place.

Comment: http://btwnthelin.es/  I just implemented the part `position: absolute;
  left: 50%;` but I left out `  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -450px;` because i think that was just to fix the size thing from the `img` tag, but instead I remvoed that, but the image is now not aligned in the center.

Comment: Margin-left and margin-top set the margin of an element.

Comment: sorry i missed the part where you asked if the style tag is being overwritten by the CSS. No it does not overwrite it, it adds to the style tag.